# loginname in autodiscover.xml for outlook

Tags: xml, outlook, imap, autodiscovery

I am trying to configure properly the autodiscover.xml file for my domains (about 30 domains).

i already set the following XML, reachable via http://autodiscover.[Domain_name]/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
<Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
<Account>
<AccountType>email</AccountType>
<Action>settings</Action>
<Protocol>
<Type>IMAP</Type>
<Server>[MY_DNS]</Server>
<Port>993</Port>
<SPA>off</SPA>
<SSL>on</SSL>
<DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
<AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
</Protocol>
</Account>
</Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

However, with this configuration, when i use the "test outlook configuration" process, the login used for IMAP does not contain the domain ( i.e. "login" and not "login@domain" ). And because i run a lot of domains, i can't just let by default the string preceding the '@' in the email address. (Because i handle  john@domain1, john@domain2, john@domain3 etc.)

I thought the xml tag DomainRequired was the key to add this domain, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the autodiscover is meant to work as a service. The POST request indicates an **EmailAddress** field, and the service must return a response based on that email address. It is not intended to build an xml file with all the different accounts of a domain. Then if you want to include the domain with the user, you must specify in the **LoginName** field, for example:

```
...
    <Account>
      <AccountType>email</AccountType>
      <Action>settings</Action>
      <Protocol>
        <Type>POP3</Type>
        <Server>contoso.com</Server>
        <Port>110</Port>
        <DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
        <LoginName>account@contoso.com</LoginName>
        <DomainName></DomainName>
        <SPA>off</SPA>
        <SSL>off</SSL>
        <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
      </Protocol>
    </Account>
...
```

You can see the Autodiscover XML schema (POST request with EmailAddress and the response) [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3)